# Why are some words spelled with “tz” if “z” already has the “ts” sound?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, consonant-sounds

I’ve never quite understood why some German words have *tz,* since the *t* doesn’t seem to provide any help in pronunciation as the sound it represents is already included in *z.*

My recent exposure is due to street names in Berlin, i.e. *Tauentzienstraße, Schieritzstraße, Gubitzstraße.* In the first, the *t* is part of *ent* and the *z* is part of *zien,* so I realize that may be due to the separate syllables. But that doesn’t apply to the other examples.

Other examples: *schnitzen, Platz, Katze, setzen, letzt, Schatz.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Tz* indicates that the preceding vowel is short; *z* doesn’t (though this may still be the case for other reasons). Most other consonants are doubled in such a situation; *z* is different for historical reasons, and instead of *zz* we write *tz.* The same thing happens to *k* and *ß:* We write *ck* instead of *kk* and *ss* instead of *ßß.*

This is § 3 of the official spelling rules:

> Für *k* und *z* gilt eine besondere Regelung.
>   (1) Statt *kk* schreibt man *ck.*
>   (2) Statt *zz* schreibt man *tz.*

Comment: Vowel length has never been my strong suit, but your explanation makes quite a bit of sense. Thanks!

Comment: Although, my impression is that this convention isn't really necessary since for historical reasons, /ts/ doesn't occur often after long vowels. But then again, I guess /k/ doesn't occur often after long vowels either (except as the result of word-final hardening in some accents, in which case it is written "g"), so "ck" also seems to be somewhat redundant.

Comment: Ironically, there is a street in Berlin named _Pestalozzistraße_, but I know that the source of that name is a Swiss person with Italian roots, so presumably different rules apply.

Comment: And also there are of course a few names that were not modified in any of the previous spelling reforms and that feature *tz* where nowadays only *z* is necessary such as *Baitz.*